# Getting a access a disposed object exception when calling QueryByIdAsync on WorkItemTrackingHttpClient

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to retrieve items from TFS to perform autodocumentation of changes and fill the maximum amount possible of information to reduce the time spent doing documentation for our client, like release notes and stuff.

I use the following method to retrieve the items, which is part of a class, both included in the body:

**Method:**

```
public IEnumerable<DTO.WorkItem> GetWorkItemsFromQuery(string queryId)
{
    using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>())
    {
        var queryResults =
            witClient
            .QueryByIdAsync(teamProjectName, new Guid(queryId))
            .Result;

        if (queryResults != null)
        {
            return queryResults
                .WorkItems
                .Select(item =>
                {
                    var workitem = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(item.Id).Result;
                    workitem.Fields.TryGetValue("DescriptionField", out object descriptionObject);
                    workitem.Fields.TryGetValue("TitleField", out object titleObject);

                    return new DTO.WorkItem()
                    {
                        Id = item.Id.ToString(),
                        Title = titleObject?.ToString() ?? string.Empty,
                        Description = descriptionObject?.ToString() ?? string.Empty
                    };
                }).ToList();
            }
            return default(IEnumerable<DTO.WorkItem>);
        }
    }
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class VSTSIssueTrackerExplorer
{
    VssConnection connection;
    private readonly string teamProjectName;

    public VSTSIssueTrackerExplorer(string tfsDefaultCollectionPath,
        string personalAccessToken,
        string teamProjectName)
    {
        connection =
            new VssConnection(
                new Uri(tfsDefaultCollectionPath),
                new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));
        this.teamProjectName = teamProjectName;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DTO.WorkItem> GetWorkItemsFromQuery(string queryId)
    {
        using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>())
        {
            var queryResults =
                witClient
                .QueryByIdAsync(teamProjectName, new Guid(queryId))
                .Result;

            if (queryResults != null)
            {
                return queryResults
                    .WorkItems
                    .Select(item =>
                    {
                        var workitem = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(item.Id).Result;
                        workitem.Fields.TryGetValue("DescriptionField", out object descriptionObject);
                        workitem.Fields.TryGetValue("TitleField", out object titleObject);

                        return new DTO.WorkItem()
                        {
                            Id = item.Id.ToString(),
                            Title = titleObject?.ToString() ?? string.Empty,
                            Description = descriptionObject?.ToString() ?? string.Empty
                        };
                    }).ToList();
            }
            return default(IEnumerable<DTO.WorkItem>);
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I call `GetWorkItemsFromQuery` everything runs fine and retrieves the items, as expected, transforming them with a select to a class `WorkItem`, shown in the following:

```
public class WorkItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

After I've retrieved the items once, if I try to retrieve them again, I get the following exception: `System.AggregateException("Cannot Access Disposed Object")`

If I remove the using block, I can call it as many times as I need so I don't have an issue with that at all.

What I would like to know is if `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` is designed to be disposed when VssConection is itself disposed or I can dispose of it when I no longer need it, I've searched online but it seems I am not capable of finding anything relevant to this matter.

Can anybody shed some light on me if not using the `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` inside a using block can be a memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's by designed. When you debug the code, you could see when you secondly retrieve the work item, `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` is cached in object `m_cachedTypes`, so you would get exception "Cannot Access Disposed Object".

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you're supposed to dispose of anything except the VssConnection itself.

Individual clients are never disposed of in Microsoft's sample code, and it appears to be the same pattern as `TfsConnection` in the old TFS SDK, i.e. there's precedent for only disposing the root object.